# Nginx Docker Angular: falied while connecting to upstream

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm trying to run Second Frontend project on Angular. I see in the error that the path is missing:
My error:

`nginx | 2022/12/10 13:36:33 [error] 104#104: *323 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /profile/home HTTP/2.0", **upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4201/home"**, host: "mysite.com"`

It's supposed to be **upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4201/PROFILE/home"**
But for some reason it's not.

My nginx.conf

```
location /profile {
        proxy_pass http://servertwo:4201/profile;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
}
```

My Docker

```
FROM node:18.8.0-alpine AS servertwo-build

WORKDIR /usr/src/servertwo

COPY . .

RUN npm ci && npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=servertwo-build  /usr/src/servertwo/dist/servertwo /var/www/html

EXPOSE 4201
```

In My angular.json :

```
"baseHref": "/profile/"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you have 1 or 2 containers? It looks like you have a reverse proxy and a container that serves your Angular app. Can you clarify?

Comment: @HansKilian I have several containers. Two of them are for frontend. The first one works fine. The second gives me a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Comment: The container you show the Dockerfile for is listening on port 80 (the Nginx default). Not 4201 as you seem to think.